# Error input not display in this scope

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that manages student information and marks. My problem is I'm getting an error e.g. input not display in this scope for lines 23,26,29,32, and 53. Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    system("Project Assignment");
    system("colr 0f");
    cout << "Please enter choice" <<endl;
    cout << "1. Input new student" <<endl;
    cout << "2. Search for student by number" <<endl;
    cout << "3. Edit an exiting student marks" <<endl;
    cout << "4. Display all students" <<endl;
    cout << "5. Exit" <<endl;

    int choice;
    cin >> choice; 

    switch (choice){
    case 1: 
        input();
        break;
    case 2:
        search();
        break;
    case 3:
        edit();
        break;
    case 4:
        displayAll();
        break;
}

    void input();
    {
        system("cls");
        string fname;
        string lname;
        string filename;
        int mark;
        int studNum;

        cout << "Input student first Name:" ;
        cin >> fname;
        cout << "Input student last name: ";
        cin >> lname;
        cout << "Input student mark: ";
        cin >> mark;
        cout << "Input student number: ";
        cin >> studNum;
        string studNum2 = to_string(studNum);
        studNum2.append(".txt");

        ofstream newstudent(studNum2);
        newstudent <<fname <<" " <<lname <<" "<<mark <<" "<<studNum << endl;
        newstudent.close();




    }
    void search();
    {

    }
    void edit();
    {

    }
    void displayall();
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm just guessing here, but there are two problems I see in your program: The first is that you are try to use *nested* function, i.e. functions inside another function. That is not allowed by the C++ standard, through some compilers might allow it as an extension to the language.

The second problem is that you don't actually *define* the functions inside the `main` function, you only *declare* them. When you do

```
int input();
{
}
```

you first have a declaration of the `input` function prototype, then you have a nested but empty scope. This problem should lead to the source actually failing to build with a linker error.

There is a third issue too, and that is that you must declare the function prototypes *before* you call the functions.

A fixed version of your program should look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Declare function prototypes, so the compiler knows these functions exist
void input();
void search();
void edit();
void displayall();

int main()
{
    ...
    // Now you can call the functions
    input();
    ...    
}

void input()  // Note: No semicolon here
{
    ...
}

void search()  // Note: No semicolon here
{
    ...
}

void edit()  // Note: No semicolon here
{
    ...
}

void displayall()  // Note: No semicolon here
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: My problem is in the switch case choice, which i have an input case, search case, etc. Im getting an error on line 23

Comment: @Netherland Did you read the about both the second *and* the third issue I pointed out? Did you look at my fixed pseudo.code, do you see how it differs from yours?

Answer (score 0):

You should **declare** functions before you use them. In particular your `input()` function is both declared and defined after its first use in `main()`.